# How to remove the borders around pictures in the mobile version of Blogger

Tags: css, mobile, blogger

I'm customizing my blog in Blogger and I want to remove the borders around the pictures; I am able to do that in the web version by simply removing the `box-shadow` attribute in `.post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img, .BlogList .item-thumbnail img`, but how can I do it in the mobile version? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.mobile` to alter your css.

For eg.

```
.mobile .date-header { 
text-decoration:underline; 
}
```

Accordingly use for images and apply 0px shadows :)